HAC standard errors in r using plm package?
I want to estimate a fixed effects model (with both country- and year fixed effects) and ADDITIONALLY apply HAC standard errors. Although I didn't get any error message after running the following code in r, I'm not really sure whether I'm actually getting HAC standard errors. Can someone please confirm? In particular, I'm getting exactly the same standard errors if I change HAC3 to HC3 or even remove the option vcovHAC (or vcovHC) completely, etc.
fe1 <- plm( log(DEB) ~ log(IMP),
                   model = "within",
                   data = data,
                   index = c("country","year"), 
                   effect = "twoways")

fe2 <- plm( log(DEB) ~ log(IMP),
                   model = "within",
                   data = data,
                   index = c("country","year"), 
                   effect = "twoways",
                   vcovHAC = "HAC3")

fe3 <- plm( log(DEB) ~ log(IMP),
                   model = "within",
                   data = data,
                   index = c("country","year"), 
                   effect = "twoways",
                   vcovHC = "HC3")


Try using the plm::vcovHC function. The type argument has the following options:  "HC0", "sss", "HC1", "HC2", "HC3", "HC4".

@MarcoSandri Thank you for your quick reply. Yes, this is now working! Thank you, much appreciated for your help. By the way, are these options HAC or only HC? I've tried to find an answer but unfortunately not successfully.

I am not sure, but using vcovHC(model, method = "arellano", type = "HC1") should yield HAC standard errors. I suggest to read this https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1468-0084.1987.mp49004006.x

You are doing it the wrong way, there is no argument vcovHAC and not vcovHC to function plm. The typical way in R to non-usual standard errors is to:

1st estimate the model
2nd estimate the non-usual standard errors separately
3rd combine the two

This approach to be very flexible as the vcov can be feed to many formatting packages/functions (3rd step), e.g., the typical summary for model summary or lmtest::coeftest. I put an example below, taken from help file ?plm::vcovHC, but there are more examples. Be sure to read the help file for all the parameters etc. you might want to set.
The plm package's vignette [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/A_plmPackage.html] has a whole section "Robust covariance matrix estimation" with examples. Also, plm's vocHC and other vcovXX functions of plm have examples.
library(plm)
data("Produc", package = "plm")
zz <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
          data = Produc, model = "random")
summary(zz, vcov = vcovHC)
#> Oneway (individual) effect Random Effect Model 
#>    (Swamy-Arora's transformation)
#> 
#> Note: Coefficient variance-covariance matrix supplied: vcovHC
#> 
#> Call:
#> plm(formula = log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, 
#>     data = Produc, model = "random")
#> 
#> Balanced Panel: n = 48, T = 17, N = 816
#> 
#> Effects:
#>                    var  std.dev share
#> idiosyncratic 0.001454 0.038137 0.175
#> individual    0.006838 0.082691 0.825
#> theta: 0.8888
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>       Min.    1st Qu.     Median    3rd Qu.       Max. 
#> -0.1067230 -0.0245520 -0.0023694  0.0217333  0.1996307 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error z-value  Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)  2.1354110  0.2386676  8.9472 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> log(pcap)    0.0044386  0.0545970  0.0813  0.935206    
#> log(pc)      0.3105484  0.0435922  7.1239 1.049e-12 ***
#> log(emp)     0.7296705  0.0699680 10.4286 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> unemp       -0.0061725  0.0023326 -2.6461  0.008141 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Total Sum of Squares:    29.209
#> Residual Sum of Squares: 1.1879
#> R-Squared:      0.95933
#> Adj. R-Squared: 0.95913
#> Chisq: 4524.65 on 4 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16

with specific arguments set:
summary(zz, vcov = function(x) vcovHC(x, method="arellano", type="HC1"))
#> Oneway (individual) effect Random Effect Model 
#>    (Swamy-Arora's transformation)
#> 
#> Note: Coefficient variance-covariance matrix supplied: function(x) vcovHC(x, method = "arellano", type = "HC1")
#> 
#> Call:
#> plm(formula = log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, 
#>     data = Produc, model = "random")
#> 
#> Balanced Panel: n = 48, T = 17, N = 816
#> 
#> Effects:
#>                    var  std.dev share
#> idiosyncratic 0.001454 0.038137 0.175
#> individual    0.006838 0.082691 0.825
#> theta: 0.8888
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>       Min.    1st Qu.     Median    3rd Qu.       Max. 
#> -0.1067230 -0.0245520 -0.0023694  0.0217333  0.1996307 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error z-value  Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)  2.1354110  0.2394021  8.9198 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> log(pcap)    0.0044386  0.0547651  0.0810  0.935404    
#> log(pc)      0.3105484  0.0437264  7.1021 1.229e-12 ***
#> log(emp)     0.7296705  0.0701833 10.3966 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> unemp       -0.0061725  0.0023398 -2.6380  0.008339 ** 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Total Sum of Squares:    29.209
#> Residual Sum of Squares: 1.1879
#> R-Squared:      0.95933
#> Adj. R-Squared: 0.95913

